# AngularJs can't run a method

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner angularjs user, but i have to learn it for my new job and I thought I could practice a bit. So I did a simple string reverse method and I thought I could make a simple calculator (exactly, only sum). Here is my code. I made 2 modules, 2 controllers and the first one is working fine, but the calculator isn't. However I made a simple site, where only the calc code is, and it works fine and I don't understand why it works, but doesn't work if 2 modules are on the same site.(Yeah, i'm a very beginner). Thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">  </script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="myController">
<center>  
<input type="text" ng-model="myString" placeholder="Enter text"/>
<p>Input: {{myString }}</p>
<p>Filtered input: {{getReverse()}}</p>
</center>
</div>
<br><br>
<center>
<div ng-app="MyCalc" ng-controller="myCalculate">
 <input type="text" ng-model="firstNumber"><br>
 <input type="text" ng-model="secondNumber"><br>
 <p> Result: {{getResult()}}</p>
 </div>
 </center>


<script>

var reverse = angular.module("MyApp", []);
var calc = angular.module("MyCalc",[]);  



  reverse.controller('myController',function($scope){
      $scope.myString = "";
      $scope.getReverse = function(){
          return $scope.myString.split("").reverse().join(""); 
      }
  });



  calc.controller('myCalculate',function($scope){
      $scope.firstNumber = 0;
      $scope.secondNumber = 0;
      $scope.getResult = function(){
          return Number($scope.firstNumber)+Number($scope.secondNumber);
      }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you should not use 2 angular app in a web page.
If you need to use different module, just make one depend on another.

Let's say your main module is `MyApp` and you need `MyCalc`'s function, you do it like this ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gung0Lny/)):

```
var calc = angular.module("MyCalc",[]);  
calc.controller('myCalculate',function($scope){
    $scope.firstNumber = 0;
    $scope.secondNumber = 0;
    $scope.getResult = function(){
        return Number($scope.firstNumber)+Number($scope.secondNumber);
    }
});
// Make MyApp module depend on MyCalc
var reverse = angular.module("MyApp", ["MyCalc"]);
reverse.controller('myController',function($scope){
    $scope.myString = "";
    $scope.getReverse = function(){
        return $scope.myString.split("").reverse().join(""); 
    }
});
```

And then in the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <center>  
            <input type="text" ng-model="myString" placeholder="Enter text"/>
            <p>Input: {{myString }}</p>
            <p>Filtered input: {{getReverse()}}</p>
        </center>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <center>
        <div ng-controller="myCalculate">
             <input type="text" ng-model="firstNumber"><br>
             <input type="text" ng-model="secondNumber"><br>
             <p> Result: {{getResult()}}</p>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

P/s: If you really need to bootstrap 2 angular app in the same web page, you need to bootstrap it manually ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otyxdzge/)):

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('calc'), ['MyCalc']);
```

`calc` is the id of the element you need to bootstrap the second app on

```
<div id="calc" ng-controller="myCalculate">
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-app directive can be used just one time in page.

> only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

But you can bootstrap manually your app. Affect id on div that contains an angular app and add this to your script (https://plnkr.co/edit/ZTW7mXx3iXm803xdYod1?p=preview):

```
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('reverse'), ['MyApp']);
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('calc'), ['MyCalc']);
```

But I agree with Vikash, create more modules and less app :)

Answer (score 0):

use ng-module instead of ng-app because ng-app can be used with one module in one page.

```
<div ng-module="MyModuleA">
<h1>Module A</h1>
<div ng-controller="MyControllerA">
    {{name}}
</div>
```

```
<div ng-module="MyModuleB">
<h1>Just Module B</h1>
<div ng-controller="MyControllerB">
    {{name}}
</div>
```

```
var moduleA = angular.module("MyModuleA", []);
moduleA.controller("MyControllerA", function($scope) {
$scope.name = "Bob A";
});

var moduleB = angular.module("MyModuleB", []);
moduleB.controller("MyControllerB", function($scope) {
$scope.name = "Steve B";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use angular ng-modules to achieve this

here is the working [link] [1]

[1] http://jsfiddle.net/j5jzsppv/111/

```
<div ng-modules="MyModuleA, MyModuleB">
<div ng-controller="myController">
 <input type="text" ng-model="myString" placeholder="Enter text"/>
    {{myString}}
    <p>Filtered input: {{getReverse()}}</p>
</div>
<div ng-controller="myCalculate">
<input type="text" ng-model="firstNumber"><br>
<input type="text" ng-model="secondNumber"><br>
<p> Result: {{getResult()}}</p>
</div>
```

```
var reverse = angular.module("MyModuleA", []);
var calc = angular.module("MyModuleB", []);
reverse.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
$scope.myString = "";
$scope.getReverse = function () {
    return $scope.myString.split("")
        .reverse()
        .join("");
}
});
calc.controller('myCalculate', function ($scope) {
$scope.firstNumber = 0;
$scope.secondNumber = 0;
$scope.getResult = function () {
    return Number($scope.firstNumber) + Number($scope.secondNumber);
}
});
```